# How do I set a proxy for firefox using Selenium webdriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    Proxy p = new Proxy();
    p.setSocksProxy("83.209.94.87:35923");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, p);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com.au");
```

This code is inside the main method. When I run this code, firefox is launched but the google url isn't followed and the proxy is not set to the one I specify in the code above. How can I fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    while (true) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver;
    String PROXY = "83.209.94.87:35923";
      //Bellow given syntaxes will set browser proxy settings using DesiredCapabilities.
      Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
      proxy.setAutodetect(false);
      proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
      proxy.setSocksProxy(PROXY);
      DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
      cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
      //Use Capabilities when launch browser driver Instance.
      driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);`
```

Comment: Add this `proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);` and
`proxy.setAutodetect(false);` after `Proxy p = new Proxy();`

Comment: I tried doing that but when my program launches firefox, the proxy setting is set to 'Use system proxy settings'. Check post for new code.

Comment: Check post again

Comment: There is a open bug which prevents you from using proxies as of now https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/764

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a bug you cannot use the Proxy object as of now. You should use the below code

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks", "83.209.94.87");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 35923);

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    driver.get("https://www.ipinfo.io");
```

The bug is discussed on https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/764 and you see what the Marionette driver do in background on below link

https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/testing/marionette/session.js#155

So above code just replicates the same

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent ages trying to figure out why my code wasn't working but the solution you provided worked!

Comment: Although the firefox browser is now being launched with the correct proxy, I am not able to visit websites on that browser. Its strange because I am able to visit websites on the same proxy when I set it to a firefox browser which I launch manually. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: I had checked and it works for me. The IP was a france based one

Comment: As of Java Selenium 4.1.1, you have to change `FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);` to `FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions().setProfile(profile));`

Comment: I am using Selenium 4 with Java, and none of these methods of setting proxy address are working for me. No errors, the proxy just doesn't take.

Answer (score 1):

Work in Selenium 3.14.2, Firefox 62, C# .NET 4.5

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"GeckoDriver19", "geckodriver.exe");
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
firefoxOptions.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
firefoxOptions.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 1080);

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, firefoxOptions);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.hbus.com/register");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set proxy details with credentials here in your automation code as above answers explained  but another way to do it without sharing your details in your java or python code with firefox profile.
firefox provides profiles, we can create profile for every user and customize it for proxy ,bookmarks etc.
windows user : open run(win+R) and type **'firefox -p'**
linux user : run command **'firefox -p'**
1- it will open a dialog box where you can create your profile then  select that profile and open firefox.
2- open a new tab and search **'about:config'** .accept the Risk and Continue then click on show all
3-here you can search and set all the property
example:
**network.proxy.type**     1
 1 for Manually
2 for Automatic proxy
for Manuall proxy -
property                     value
network.proxy.http                    your proxy ip
network.proxy.http_port                   port number
network.proxy.ssl                      your proxy ip
network.proxy.ssl_port                  port number
network.proxy.ftp                  your proxy ip
network.proxy.ftp_port                  port number

(to find your profile name )
Linux :  **cd .mozilla/firefox/**
windows: Press. +R on the keyboard. A Run dialog will open.
         Type in: %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
         Click OK. A window will open containing profile folders
now load this profile in java code

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile(new File("path of your profile"));
options.setProfile(profile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path of gecko driver");
driver.get("url");
```

Answer (score -1):

With Java-Selenium version 4.1.1, the following code works for me:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

...

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("myproxy:80");
proxy.setSslProxy("myproxy:80");

FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProxy(proxy);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

If you like, you can wrap everything up in one line:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions().setProxy(new Proxy().setHttpProxy("myproxy:80").setSslProxy("myproxy:80")));
```

For further proxy settings see: [Selenium Proxy API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Proxy.html)